# What can I do to get actual prepared statements in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My company wants to use WordPress for their Internet site and my main concern is the use of prepared statements. According to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139431), and I read the source code myself in disbelief, WordPress sanitizes string but is **not** prepared at the database.

Is there anything I can do to get the real thing? Or are my concerns unfounded?

Comment: According to [`wpdb::prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/), WordPress does in fact sanitize the full SQL string before execution; there is **NO binding of variables** for proper SQL injection prevention. If this concerns you then you are certainly free to incorporate the `mysqli_*` or PDO classes into your code instead of relying on wpdb. Also see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/174591/81625

Comment: I've looked into using PDO with WordPress pretty extensively and never found anything which utilises it correctly. There was a ticket raised years ago to rework `$wpdb` to use PDO correctly, but it just ended up switching from `mysql_` to `mysqli_` functions because it would be too much work. I doubt based on the long discussion which was had, this (correct usage of prepared statements) will ever make it in to core. The ticket: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21663

Comment: @naththedeveloper In my custom applications/pages I use mysqli prepared statements so I at least have the covered, but do WordPress itself do this or not? If it doesn't then can it handles things like "SELECT SOURCE FROM LIBRARY_RECORD WHERE LIBRARY_RECORD_ID = 6550" or (1,2)=(select*from(select name_const(CHAR(111,108,111,108,111,115,104,101,114),1),name_const(CHAR(111,108,111,108,111,115,104,101,114),1))a) -- "x"="x", which came out of the server log this morning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## History

Understand that the [`wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class, originally [a fork](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/b2-include/wp-db.php?rev=112) of [Justin Vincent's ezSQL library](http://justinvincent.com/ezsql), was introduced [way back in 2003](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_0.71), only [a couple of months](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315075138/http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/news-4-1-0.html) after the MySQL prepared statement protocol was released and more than [a year before](http://news.php.net/php.announce/50) PHP had *any* API support for accessing it: WordPress thus did the only thing it then could, and required any variables to be concatenated directly into dynamic SQL.

Back then, ezSQL (and thus WordPress) [used](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/b2-include/wp-db.php?rev=114#L67) PHP's [`mysql_escape_string()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) function to escape such literals—and were therefore ignorant of the database connection's actual encoding (a threat that had only been addressed in PHP itself [just a few months earlier](https://secure.php.net/releases/4_3_0.php)).

This remained WordPress's (only) defence against SQL injection [for nearly two years](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_1.5), whereupon it [switched](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/1545) to using (the even less safe) [`addslashes()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) for escaping—a situation that then remained in place [*for over four years*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_2.8) until [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) was *finally* [utilised](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/10597) (albeit [`wpdb::prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) had been [introduced](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/5778) in [the interim](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_2.3))!

It then wasn't for [*another* five years](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.9) until WordPress even began [using](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/27250) a driver *capable* of native statement preparation (i.e. [MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)): this now just under two years ago and, as @naththedeveloper [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206366/what-can-i-do-to-get-actual-prepared-statements-in-wordpress#comment63837372_38206366), the discussion in [ticket #21663](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21663) suggests that using native prepared statements may not even be on a to-do list.

## Status Quo

Unfortunately, since the MySQLi object is [a protected member](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php?rev=37837#L556) of the `wpdb` class for which there's no getter (and is assigned internally [during instantiation](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php?rev=37837#L1467)), there's no way that you can use native prepared statements with WordPress's database connection (at least, not without modifying/replacing `wpdb` with your own class).

> Is there anything I can do to get the real thing?

You can, of course, open your own/separate connection to the database over which you have complete flexibility to do as you wish.

> Or are my concerns unfounded?

As great as native statement preparation is (and I agree that it really should be the default defence strategy against SQL injection in any new project), it does also have [its downsides](http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2008/pdo_mysqlnd-prepared-statements-again/#procon).  Careful escaping of one's variables for use as SQL literals (as done by PDO's prepared statement emulation, for example; and which is what `wpdb::prepare()` these days attempts to deliver) *should* be resistant to all known attacks...

Comment: Good expansion on my initial comment, I didn't know all of this, so +1 for helping me learn something today