# using a PHP string in mysql, isset not solving the undefined vairable issue

Tags: php

I am trying to take some data and compare it against a MYSQL statement. My data is a string which with my limited knowledge is causing me difficulties. Before anyone closes this question and refers me to the main SO question about an unidentified offset or the like, I have tried that and followed the isset but still am having problems. Here is what I have:

The data is a query string. `string(125) "Customer_FName=r&Customer_LName=r&Customer_MobileNumber=2&Customer_Email=r%40rco.com&Reservation_Message=&C_Preference_Notes=" 0` to get this into my PHP function, I used `$form_data = $_POST['form_data'];`.

I then used this code:

```
parse_str($form_data, $data);
$test=isset($data['Customer_FName']) ? $data['Customer_FName'] : '';
$c_duplicate_check=$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Customer_FName=$test"));
echo($c_duplicate_check);
```

This produces the undiexined index despite using the `isset`. I have also tried:

```
$c_duplicate_check=$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Customer_FName='$data["Customer_FName"]'"));
echo($c_duplicate_check);
```

Same issue. How do I make this work? I feel like I have read the whole internet on this.

P.S.
vardump($data)
I get -

```
array(6) { 
    ["Customer_FName"]=> string(3) "ted" 
    ["Customer_LName"]=> string(5) "smith" 
    ["Customer_MobileNumber"]=> string(12) "555-555-5555" 
    ["Customer_Email"]=> string(7) "e@e.com" 
    ["Reservation_Message"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["C_Preference_Notes"]=> string(0) "" 
}
```

Comment: `isset()` is operating on `$data`, not `$form_data_array`

Comment: thanks sorry to waste time but it was a typo from the 300 attempts I have made at this. I updated above and correctly was using the isset, still does not work

Comment: I get the feeling this is an AB question: You’re asking B, when the problem is A. On your previous post, it was evident that something is hinky with the way you’re getting the query string. How exactly are you getting that, through a redirect or through ajax?  The point is, unless you are *specifically sending that exact string*, something isn’t working right. Fix that, and the rest is academic...

Comment: @tim I keep asking it different ways since none of the solutions presented have worked so I try and explain better. Now that the way the code string is being parse_str I have new problems. Its not so academic for me otherwise I wouldnt be asking the question. I did go back and answer your question by posting the ajax on the previous question which someone thoughtlessly closed

Comment: `https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php` ... Not expecting a double quote char to start the string.

Comment: @getset thanks where are you referring to the double quotes? In the MYSQL? Those have to be there. The `vardump` was put into this format by someone else.

Comment: Ok. Nevermind on vardump. But here, you need quotations to delimit the string var by reference, `WHERE Customer_FName=$test` ... regarding `$test`. Wrap in single quotes or whatever quote style is appropriate.

Comment: Possibly update your question per @TangentiallyPerpendicular. Your current code still shows `$form_data_array` instead of `$data` in your 2nd query example.

Comment: @getset thanks I did try wrapping the `$test` in the mysql statement in quotes, double, single and without, all the same undefined offset error on that front. Edited above. Missed that one. (Previously have another thing call form_data_array. Not used in the above example.

Comment: But if you dont update your code here with your changes, you dont get the incremental help you desire on face value, without a thorough of reading of comments

Comment: my mistake on missing that, sorry.

Comment: `"Customer_FName"` will cause a syntax error because you already use the `"` char to define your outer literal. You can break up your literal with append notation (a period) `.` Or you can escape your quotes. Either way. Prepared statement would be better way and has other advantages on security.

Comment: Yes I have had that issue. I have been trying to google for the last 7 minutes where to put the "." in this example and must not be google searching the right thing. I have tried phrases like append notation php, break up literal etc. Currently I have `Customer_FName='$data."Customer_FName"'` which I know is incorrect. :/

Comment: While I’ve been gone I see that this has drifted from post to ajax to quoting to mysql to prepared statements. But has the original problem been solved? Are you able to get the customer fname, lname, mobile number etc? If not, then all this other stuff is just noise. Sending a query string via post is rather odd, but if that’s the data so be it. If you *are* successfully extracting the information from the query string then we have a whole new question; but if not, don’t bring mysql into it. Solve one thing at a time, it’s much easier ;)  I’m going to be out, but I’ll check back later

Answer (score 1):

You are using the prepared statement wrong - the way you are doing it does not protect you from SQL injections.

[Read up on the topic as it is DB 101 in many languages, not just PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Example prepared query using mysqli:

```
  $mysqli = new mysqli();
  $mysqli->connect('hostname','username','password','database');
  $query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Customer_FName=(?)";
  $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
  $statement->bind_param('s',$Customer_FName);
  $statement->execute();
  $result = $statement->get_result();
  $result = $result->fetch_all();
  $statement->close();
  var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thanks but this isnt about prepared statements. That is not the issue and doesnt matter until the PHP problem is solved.

Comment: Just run the snippet I provided, I've checked on my database with different values for column name and table, it works.

Comment: Whole point of prepared statements, aside from performance 
 and security considerations is not to let the query be changed by the input data which is what you are currently doing without quoting the Customer_FName value.

Comment: Good point @tybin. Whether OP takes your advice, another story

Comment: Thank you but I can not use this because this is wordpress which is why my code looks different. There is the global $wpdb which allows me to reference the $wpdb->prepared. IS it the suggestion that the prepared usage as I have it is preventing the variable from being able to be applied?

Comment: The rule is the same regardless of the framework or method of connecting. I suggest checking the official wordpress documentation for your version, latest can be found here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/. Basically you want to ensure that whatever it is in the file is being applied to the query as an argument and not as a part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Using the information provided, I put the following into an online php sandbox:

```
$form_data = "Customer_FName=r&Customer_LName=r&Customer_MobileNumber=2&Customer_Email=r%40rco.com&Reservation_Message=&C_Preference_Notes=";
parse_str($form_data, $data);
var_dump($data);
$test=isset($data['Customer_FName']) ? $data['Customer_FName'] : '';
var_dump($test);
```

This generated the following result:

```
array(6) {
  ["Customer_FName"]=>
  string(1) "r"
  ["Customer_LName"]=>
  string(1) "r"
  ["Customer_MobileNumber"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["Customer_Email"]=>
  string(9) "r@rco.com"
  ["Reservation_Message"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["C_Preference_Notes"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(1) "r"
```

So, aside from the provided data not matching the var dump that you provided for `$data`, you can clearly see that you can successfully extract the data from `$form_data`.

The undefined index is therefore being generated in your (malformed) call to `$wpdb->prepare()`.

I took a simplified version of the prepare method and put it in the sandbox:

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

$form_data = "Customer_FName=r&Customer_LName=r&Customer_MobileNumber=2&Customer_Email=r%40rco.com&Reservation_Message=&C_Preference_Notes=";
parse_str($form_data, $data);
var_dump($data);
$test=isset($data['Customer_FName']) ? $data['Customer_FName'] : '';
var_dump($test);

function prepare( $query, ...$args ) {
    $passed_as_array = false;
    if ( is_array( $args[0] ) && count( $args ) === 1 ) {
        $passed_as_array = true;
        $args            = $args[0];
    }
    foreach($args as $arg) {
        print $arg;
    }
}

prepare("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Customer_FName=$test");
```

And got the following result:

```
array(6) {
  ["Customer_FName"]=>
  string(1) "r"
  ["Customer_LName"]=>
  string(1) "r"
  ["Customer_MobileNumber"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["Customer_Email"]=>
  string(9) "r@rco.com"
  ["Reservation_Message"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["C_Preference_Notes"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(1) "r"
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 0 in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
```

Bingo!  There's the undefined offset.  You have successfully found a place where wordpress did not user-proof their code.

Now, what's the fix? Use the prepare method correctly.

The [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) gives some really sucky examples, so here's what you need to know:

You must supply at least two arguments:

> wpdb::prepare( string $query, mixed $args )

Placeholders are explained this way:

> Uses sprintf()-like syntax. The following placeholders can be used in the query string: %d (integer) %f (float) %s (string)
> All placeholders MUST be left unquoted in the query string. A corresponding argument MUST be passed for each placeholder.

So for your query, you would use

```
$wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Customer_FName=%s",$test);
```

I don't use wordpress, so I'm guessing on this, but the rest of your sample script should probably look like this:

```
$c_duplicate_check = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Customer_FName=%s",
        $test
    )
);
print_r($c_duplicate_check); // result will be an array, so use print_r
```

Note, WordPress doesn't *really* prepare queries; they are just escaping values.  Why they don't fix this, I have no idea.  Just something to keep in mind, because if they ever do fix it you'll want to upgrade immediately. If I were to use WP, I'd undoubtedly roll my own CRUD object.

Comment: To my understanding prepare from WP works the same as PDO and mysqli. The placeholders are just sprintf format. PDO and mysql do the escaping as well. There's no other way to do it. Letting the driver do it accounts for all scenarios. If you view processlist in mysql the queries don't execute with placeholders, values are swapped in and replaced.

Comment: @user3783243 Thanks, I'll look into that some more.  I sure do see a lot of preg_replace and similar gymnastics (like `array_walk( $args, array( $this, 'escape_by_ref' ) );`) in that method, whereas PDO and mysqli seem to accept the data as is.

Comment: @user3783243 good discussion of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38214348/2129574.  Regarding PDO, it looks like it depends on whether the driver supports prepared statements - *"PDO will emulate prepared statements/bound parameters for drivers that do not natively support them, and can also rewrite named or question mark style parameter markers to something more appropriate, if the driver supports one style but not the other."* So to my understanding, if the driver doesn't support it, PDO will fudge (emulate) it.  OTOH, WP will always fudge it.  That being said, I'm no expert...